# NSLog NSString* print doesn't print

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nslog

I am having problems with NSLog method and some objects. My objects return an NSString*, but the string is concatenated with several other strings like this :

```
-(NSString*) identiteSimple
{
    NSString *res = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:prenom];
    res = [res stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    res = [res stringByAppendingString:nom];
    return res;
}
```

however, when I try to print it using NSLog like this :

```
NSLog([myObj identiteSimple]);
```

Xcode warns me that:

> "Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)"

And nothing gets printed. Does anyone have any idea why the NSString doesn't get printed?

Comment: you should always use `NSLog(@"%@", [myObj identiteSimple]);` even though what you had will work in most cases, because if the string contains a percent sign your code will crash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comments to other answers, you're not actually allocating memory for your `Personne` object.

```
Personne *moi = [moi initWithName:@"Lennon" prenom:@"John" civilite:@"Mr"];
```

`moi` is `nil` when you try to call `initWithName:prenom:civilite:`. Messages to `nil` do nothing and return `nil`, so `moi` will still be `nil`, and `identiteSimple` will also return `nil` when you call `NSLog()`.

Comment: so i only need to create my Personne object before using it ? like this perhaps : `Personne *moi = [[Personne alloc]  initWithName:@"Lennon" prenom:@"John" civilite:@"Mr"];` ?

Answer (score 4):

You should try :

```
NSLog(@"%@", [myObj identiteSimple]);
```

Comment: oh yeah, i forgot to add that i already tried that. it prints      2011-03-17 19:27:17.894 objc[13127:903] (null)

Comment: it seams to be showing the default description method of the object rather the identiteSimple method. i can't figure out why.

Comment: Don't you forget the "prenom" parameter ?

Comment: no, it's created with the object, as a parameter of the constructor. same for nom

Comment: Mmmmh you could use `initWithFormat` :

NSString *res = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",prenom,nom];

Comment: it's printing `2011-03-17 19:41:23.353 objc[13977:903] (null)`

Comment: Check your two parameters `nom` and `prenom`.

Comment: please see my constructor method above, to see if nom and prenom are badly created.

Comment: @aliouftw: you should still never use a string you want to print as the format. if the string you get from [myObj identiteSimple] contains a percent sign, it will crash your program

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are leaking memory for `res`. You are allocating that, then pointing it to new string without releasing the alloced one.

```
NSString *res = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:prenom];

// after this line res points to new string, leaking previous alloced memory
res = [res stringByAppendingString:@" "];
```

Instead of alloc you should create autoreleased string here.

```
NSString *res = [NSString stringWithString:prenom];
res = [res stringByAppendingString:@" "];
res = [res stringByAppendingString:nom];
```

Or even beteter:

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", prenom, nom];
```

My guess about not printing is that `prenom` or `nom` is not a valid NSString. You should post their code too. And you can debug by checking `res` after every new string to find out where it is breaking.

Something like this:

```
NSString *res = [NSString stringWithString:prenom];
NSLog(prenom);  // prenom is OK
NSLog(res);     // res is OK here

res = [res stringByAppendingString:@" "];
NSLog(res);    // res is OK here too

res = [res stringByAppendingString:nom];
NSLog(nom);    // nom is OK
NSLog(res);    // final content of res
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `-(Personne*) initWithParam:(NSString*) n :(NSString*) p : (NSString*) c{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        nom = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:n];
        prenom = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:p];
        civilite = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:c];
        maison = nil;
    }
    
    return self;
}`

Comment: Verify that you are passing correct parameters and none of nom and prenom is null.

Comment: no they're both created like this `Personne *moi = [moi initWithName:@"Lennon" prenom:@"John" civilite:@"Mr"];`

Comment: Check the answer of Steve Madsen. You have problem in the above line.

Comment: you should always use `NSLog(@"%@", prenom);`, etc. instead of `NSLog(prenom);`